# Pushing images to GCR from Jenkins pipeline taking too long time

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I am having my Jenkins pipeline code as below

```
def app_image
def app_latest
def queue_image
def queue_latest
def migrate_image
def migrate_latest

environment {
project_id="us.gcr.io/staging-123"
artifact_app="app"
artifact_queue="queue"
migration_artifact="backend-migration"  
credentials_id="staging_cred"
}

pipeline {
  agent any
stages {
  stage('Start') {
        def git_hash=sh returnStdout:true, script:'git rev-parse HEAD'
        version="${git_hash.trim()}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        app_image="${env.project_id}/${env.artifact_app}:${version}"
        app_latest="${env.project_id}/${env.artifact_app}:latest"
        queue_image="${env.project_id}/${env.artifact_queue}:${version}"
        queue_latest="${env.project_id}/${env.artifact_queue}:latest"
        migrate_image="${env.project_id}/${env.migration_artifact}:${version}"
        migrate_latest="${env.project_id}/${env.migration_artifact}:latest"
    

}

 stage('Build images and push to GCR') {
        when { anyOf { branch 'develop'; branch 'qa'; branch 'staging'; branch 'master' } }
        steps {
            container("docker"){
                withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: "gcr:${credentials_id}", url: 'https://us.gcr.io') {
                   sh """
                   docker pull ${app_latest}    
                   docker build -f ./Dockerfile.app --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --cache-from ${app_latest} --tag ${app_image} --tag ${app_latest} .
                   docker push ${app_image}
                   docker push ${app_latest}
                 
                   
                   docker pull ${queue_latest}
                   docker build -f ./Dockerfile.queue --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --cache-from ${queue_latest} --tag ${queue_image} --tag ${queue_latest} .
                   docker push ${queue_image}
                   docker push ${queue_latest}
                   
                   
                   docker pull ${migrate_latest}
                   docker build -f ./Dockerfile.migrate --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --cache-from ${migrate_latest} --tag ${migrate_image} --tag ${migrate_latest} .
                   docker push ${migrate_image}
                   docker push ${migrate_latest}                    
                   """                       
                        }                               
            }       
        
        }       
        
      }

     }  
}
```

Whenever new code merged to the any one of the branches pipeline will take the code it will build and push the images to GCR. 1st time while pushing images to GCR each push is taking around 2 mins, we have 6 images. Total time only for pushing images will be around 12 mins, Next deployment phase will be there that will take around 3 mins overall job time 15 mins

When we ran the same build 2nd time it is pushing images to GCR very fast.

Is there any way to push images first time to GCR from pipeline fast around 1 mins

Answer (score 0):

I need some clarification about what you meant by "second time". Is it the second time you run the same build with same values? If you are updating a Docker image then it will only build the layers that need to be updated so it would be obviously faster. You can't make this faster on the first time around since it needs to build all the layers.

On the other hand, if you were to take each of the three blocks and split them in to parallel stages, then all the images will be built and pushed together. This might improve the speed of things (assuming you have the necessary spare resources). Refer to the [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) for more info.

Comment: Second time means running same builds with same values

Comment: docker build is not taking much time only pushing to GCR for the new code images taking time